# I'm new at Ubuntu, and for my job I am asked to show this. How can I access to this information?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ping, testing, helpfile

I'm supposed to send this information but I don't know how to do that.

I tried pinging cabinet.skyeng.ru but it continues processing.

[image: here]

Comment: Press Ctrl + C.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is a Windows program - how exactly does your question relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: @steeldriver I took this question to mean "I've been given instructions for Windows, but I run a Ubuntu machine, how do I do this? " On Windows, the default is to stop after four pings, whereas on Ubuntu it goes on until stopped by Ctrl + C.

Comment: Use `ping -c 4 cabinet.skyeng.ru` ... the -c <number> tells ping how many times to ping the server.

Comment: @Jos that was my reading as well - but the question needs improvement to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

Linux uses different ping implementation then Windows, on Windows you will use `/n` or `-n` to specify how many packets to send, on Ubuntu you would use `-c` to specify number of packets.

Ubuntu version of ping with 100 packets.

```
ping cabinet.skyeng.ru -c 100
```

Is equal to `ping cabinet.skyeng.ru -n 100` on Windows that you have on the picture you provided.

On Linux `ping -n` means not to lookup symbolic names for numeric values.

On Windows if you don't specify number of packets ping will send 4 packets and then stop running and output the result.

On Linux if you don't specify number of packets to send ping will keep running until you use Ctrl+C to stop it.